# Error when creating extension: Looks like you need access to this dev store

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I Have created my PHP Shopify app and am trying to add a checkout ui extension,

As soon as I add one, I get the error below,
Looks like you need access to this dev store ((​https://myshopname.myshopify.com​))                               │
│  • Log in to the store directly from this URL (​https://myshopname.myshopify.com/admin​). If you're the store    owner,      │
│  then that direct log in should solve your access issue.
│  • If you're not the owner, create a dev store staff account for yourself. Then log in directly from the link above.

Even if I do log in manually again I get the same error.
I have enabled Checkout UI extensions under App setup as well.
If I delete the checkout extension, I am able to log in via the cli again

I have tried:
Logging in manually
Different extensions - All work except for the checkout ui
Different Browser

All with the same error

Answer (score 0):

With that email which you are owner create a admin user.

For me worked

Comment: Unfortunately, that gives me an "Email already belongs to a member" prompt.

Comment: Hmm i faced this too, create new admin user with other email and logout from shopify partners and logout from store and try to access your store from the link 

https://myshopname.myshopify.com/admin​ and try to access with the new user admin you created